# How to copy projects in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, project

When I copy the project in Eclipse, then a new project is copied named

```
copy of project
```

Now when I run it, then the URL bar still says the old project name in title.

Where is the reference stored so that I can run using new project name?

Comment: Can you give a bit more info? What type of project are you referring to? How do you run it; and where do you see the URL bar?

Comment: what kind of project? what server? details pls...

Comment: Watch out for metadata associated with team support (SVN, CVS, etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are referring to a copying a web project and the URL corresponds to the context root of the web app. You can change it at Project Properties -> Web Project Settings -> Context Root.

Answer (score 4):

The projects name is written in the `.project` file inside the project folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<projectDescription>
    <name>project-name</name>
    <!-- ... -->
</projectDescription>
```

Open that file with any text editor or from inside eclipse (you'll see it if you switch to *Navigator View*)

Answer (score 1):

You have to copy the whole project tree, ad then you need to open the ".project" file in the copy. Replace the project name at the top of the xml file, and then you can reimport it.

You also have to copy/edit the launch configurations. You can find them in the workspace directory (search for *.launch files), and edit them.